# Eclipse won't run, can't find a solution that works

Tags: java, eclipse, path

When I try to run Eclipse, I get this error:

[image]

I know this question has been asked numerous times here, but I've tried many fixes and nothing works. I have a JRE in my path. Here is my PATH variable: `%Path%;%ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS%;%ANDROID_TOOLS%;C:\pspsdk\bin,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40;%VPROJECT%\..\bin`

I also tried adding the JAVA_HOME variable to user variables but that didn't help either. I also added -vm with the path to my jdk to the eclipse.ini, but had no luck. What else can I try? I did transition to Android Studio and I love it, but there are still a few things I need Eclipse for and would like to get it working. I've had this problem for months now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post your eclipse.ini in the question

Comment: I think you need the `\bin` subdirectory in your PATH after `jdk1.7.0_40`, or `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: Eclipse has versions that *bundle* the appropriate runtime (under .\jre) (actually, I've never used a version that did not) .. make sure that `C:\eclipse` is where eclipse is *actually* installed. If it is moved then the shortcut to launch it may have an incorrect working directory.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Here is my eclipse.ini
http://pastebin.com/8ZcSkrbB

Comment: Perhaps you're using 32bit eclipse and 64bit jdk, or vice-versa. Also try to add the vm in the shortcut, something like: c:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin"

Comment: @hsilomedus Just tried that and got a little bit farther. Now I get the splash screen and another error that says "Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program
Files\lava\jdk1 .7.0_40\bin\..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll""

Comment: It could still be a 32 vs 64 bit problem  1) `java -version` from a command prompt will tell you if you have a 64-bit JRE, 2) `c:\Program files` is for 64-bit programs on a 64-bit Windows; `c:\Program files (x86)` is for 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Windows, 3) I'm guessing that maybe you have a 64-bit Windows, a 64-bit JDK ... and a 32-bit Eclipse.

Comment: I downloaded a new 64 bit version of eclipse and added -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin" and it works just fine. But the other version of eclipse did work in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `\bin` jdk subdirectory to your PATH:

```
. . . C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin; . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is not on your path. Here are a few solutions:

Add `C:\path\to\java\bin` to PATH

or start eclipse with the following option:

`eclipse -vm C:\path\to\java\bin`

or add the following to eclipse.ini (a sibling of eclipse.exe in the eclipse install dir)

```
-vm
eclipse -vm C:\path\to\java\bin
```